# How to remove "$" from a float column of Dataframe

Tags: python, replace, numbers

How to remove `$` from a float column of `Dataframe`?

I tried the command:

```
fake["AmountPaid"] = fake["AmountPaid"].apply(lambda x: 
x.replace(",",""))
```

I received the following error:

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

If i convert to string before, the values in the column just mess everything.

Comment: Can you post a sample of `fake["AmountPaid"] ` ?

Comment: A float column can by definition not include any `$`. If you have `$`, you have a string column

Comment: I guess you can just use `fake.str.replace('$','')` instead of using apply. But you want to remove '$', and in your code you are removing commas, so very confusing.

Comment: @anishtain4, worked well your tip! tks!